# Как получить текущее значение флага на yii?

Tags: php, yii2

Как получить доступ к атрибуту checked ?
Когда я пытаюсь вывести значение переменной $flag она ровняется null

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'flag')->checkBox(['label'=>'Do you want to send an email template?','checked'=>false])?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `action` Вашего контроллера, который обрабатывает `submit` формы делаете следующее

```php
        //тут укажите название Вашей модели формы в которой указано свойство $flag
        $myForm = new myForm(); 
        //Получен POST-запрос?
        if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            //загружаем данные из POST-запроса в модель
            if ( $myForm->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) )  {
                //валидируем модель, вдруг какое-то из полей заполнено некорректно
                if ( $model->validate() ) {
                   $flag = $model->flag;
                }
            }
        }
```